# Oracle PLSQL extend type with date abs timestamp

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, forall

I have the following code, which seems to be working. Is there a way I can add a date, timestamp to the type definition? If so, how would reference the columns so I can INSERT data into them. For example, let's say I want to add 10 seconds to SYSDATE and SYSTIMESTAMP for each new row?

```
 create table t ( x int );

 declare
      type numlist is table of number index by pls_integer;
      s numlist;
    begin
      for i in 1 .. 100000
      loop
        s(i) := i;
      end loop;
      forall i in 1 .. 100000
      insert into t values (s(i));
   end;
   /
```

Comment: yes you need to create a RECORD.   https://www.guru99.com/pl-sql-record-type.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using exactly the same method as you did with numbers:

```sql
create table t ( x int, y DATE, z TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE );
```

Then

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE numlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  TYPE datelist IS TABLE OF DATE;
  TYPE timestamplist IS TABLE OF TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
  xs numlist       := numlist();
  ys datelist      := datelist();
  zs timestamplist := timestamplist();

  n     CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER              := 100;
  nowd  CONSTANT DATE                     := SYSDATE;
  nowts CONSTANT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE := SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  xs.EXTEND(n);
  ys.EXTEND(n);
  zs.EXTEND(n);
  FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
    xs(i) := i;
    ys(i) := nowd + (i - 1) * INTERVAL '10' SECOND;
    zs(i) := nowts + (i - 1) * INTERVAL '10' SECOND;
  END LOOP;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. n
    INSERT INTO t (x, y, z) VALUES (xs(i), ys(i), zs(i));
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5c8f64e0b4f3b3eb9518a434167a233a)*

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  c1 INT,
  dt DATE
);

DECLARE
  TYPE numlist IS
    TABLE OF t%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  s    numlist;
  l_dt DATE := sysdate;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    s(i).c1 := i;
    s(i).dt := l_dt;
    l_dt := l_dt + INTERVAL '10' SECOND;
  END LOOP;

  FORALL i IN 1..10
    INSERT INTO t (
      c1,
      dt
    ) VALUES (
      s(i).c1,
      s(i).dt
    );

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type and array of type like so

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE example_type IS OBJECT (
    your_num             NUMBER,
    time      TIMESTAMP,
    date      DATE
    );

CREATE TYPE array_of_example_type IS TABLE OF example_type;
```

Then you can cycle through like:

```
FOR i in array_of_example_type.FIRST .. array_of_example_type.LAST
LOOP 
END;
```

Then use oracle functions like add_months(), add_years(), to_date() to add whatever you want.

In the for loop, you can reference the object if the data is already in the object like:

```
array_of_example_type(i).your_num;
array_of_example_type(i).date;
array_of_example_type(i).time;
```